# On MacOS, I successfully login into MS Teams, then get taken back to select a User screen. How do I break MS Teams login loop?

Tags: macos, microsoft-teams

Sometimes, when I go to log into Teams after maybe a password or account change, it successfully logs me in, but then I get taken back to the select an account screen. How can I break the cycle?

Steps:

I select my account from the list:

[image: Login User Select Screen for Teams]

Then go through the MFA process, I receive a text message, and It succeeds, and I get returned to the select account screen.

What gives?
How do I break this loop?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to logging out Via your Icon in the top right corner.

1. Close the "Pick an Account" screen.

[image: Login User Select Screen for Teams]

2. Then you'll have access to your icon, click on the icon, and Sign out. (although the screen may vary from this screenshot) [image: Login User Select Screen for Teams]
3. Sign back in again, go thru MFA cycle and you should be able good!

We ran into this issue A couple times on MacOs, and this fixed it every time!